# Tensorflow running time detect

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been training a TF2 model like

```
class MyModel():
    def __init__(self):

        self.inp = Input(name='inp', shape=[None, self.inp_tgt.n_feat], dtype='float32')
        self.network = MyAttentionModel()
        self.model = Model(inputs=self.inp, outputs=self.network.outp)
        self.model.summary()

    def train(self):

        train_dataset = self.dataset(max_epochs)
        opt = Adam()
        loss = BinaryCrossentropy()
        self.model.compile(loss=loss,optimizer=opt)
        self.model.fit(
            x=train_dataset,
            epochs=max_epochs,
            steps_per_epoch=self.n_iter
            )
```

The issue is the **training precess runs too slow**, I've checked each inner function in my model offline, but things seem to work fine seperately.

I'd like to use `datetime.now()` to check the time used in each part of my model like I use in pytorch. But in tensorflow, program seems not running seriesly, thus `print(end_time - start_time)` output nothing

There're some method I've tried,

- `print` time costed
- cProfile
- tensorflow-profiler

`cProfile` and `tensorflow-profiler` outputs mainly python operation's time cost, which difficult to find the bottleneck in my model.

Is there any other methods may help if I want to calculate the time cost of each component of the network?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Callbacks to check the time per each epoch.

```
class TimeCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.times = []

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.epoch_time_start = time.time()

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.times.append(time.time() - self.epoch_time_start)
        print(self.times[epoch])
```

And then pass this as a callback to the `model.fit` function like below

```
cb=TimeCallback()
model1.fit(x=train_batch,validation_data=valid_batch,epochs=10,verbose=2,callbacks=cb)
```

The output will be as follows

```
Epoch 1/10
162.60295152664185
57/57 - 163s - loss: 38.3437 - accuracy: 0.5433 - val_loss: 7.4644 - val_accuracy: 0.5890 - 163s/epoch - 3s/step
Epoch 2/10
161.40023803710938
57/57 - 161s - loss: 3.3678 - accuracy: 0.6856 - val_loss: 3.4822 - val_accuracy: 0.6160 - 161s/epoch - 3s/step
```

Comment: thx for your ans, I wonder is there any way to calulate time cost of each component of the model?